# React not rendering inside the index.html div#app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am learning React and I am attempting to render a basic component on the page. How ever nothing seems to be working. At the same time I am not getting any errors during the build, or in the browser inspector, and i cant seem to pinpoint the source of the problem.

my index html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Test</title>
     <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    </head>

   <body>
     <div id="app">

      </div>
      <script type="text/babel" src="bundle.js"></script>
   </body>

  </html>
```

This appends to the browser just fine, if i was to insert text or an element into the body tag, it renders...

My index.jsx ( the entree point for the app) is as follows :

```
 import React from 'react'
 import {render} from 'react-dom'
 import App from './components/App.jsx'

 render(
     <div> <h1>Hello World</h1> </div>,
     document.getElementById('app')
 );
```

My webpack.config.dev.js is as follows :

```
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {

  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    path.join(__dirname, '/client/index.jsx')
],
output: {
    path: '/',
    publicPath: '/'
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
],
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            include: [
                path.join(__dirname, 'client')
            ],
            loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
        }

    ]

},
  devtool: "eval-source-map"
}
```

Please note that the project file structure is as follows 
Client
    - index.jsx
Server
    - server.js
    - index.html

Thank you in advanced for any help, as it is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? You may need to add presets for your loaders

Comment: there are no errors in the console . My .babelrc contains the presets 
` {
   "presets": [ "latest", "react" ]
   }
`

Comment: What does App.jsx look like?

Comment: @MattHolland
`
  import React from 'react';

   class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
            <h1> Hello </h1>
        );
       }
   }

   export default App 
`
But in this case i dont think it matters because i cant get it to render either, thats why i tried rendering just the simple <div> with hello world <h1>s ... which also doesnt render ....